# Few questions about hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have few questions about hibernate

1. I have ask basic question: a persistent identity can have a corresponding row in the database. So, what are the advantages of `Persist` object in hibernate?
2. How to fetch last row from table using hibernate and Oracle?
3. In my application saving the personal information i.e. employeename, dateofbirth, dateofjoining etc. We are storing employee name first name, surname, last name in database. For example:

   ```
   Firstname Lastname 
   =======    ======  
   Rinkan     John
   ```

   How to retrieve `Rinkan John` from hibernate objects?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is used to store objects in a databse, this means rather than retreiving data using a standard sql query, and then constructing your objects you don;t need to worry about this at all, instead you just access your persistant data store as if it were a container for all your objects, often accessed by their id.

For me the advantage of using hibernate is that I do not have to deal with non object based code as hibernate does it all for me.

Fetching the last row is in a way a non object way of doing things.  You can access the last object represented by your databse table/tables.

As for your employee, to me you would have an Employee entity which when your application is deployed would create a table appropriatley structured to hold an Employee object.  You don't really need to worry too much about how it actually structures the table as you will only ever deal with the Employee objects not the sql itself.